# Diffrence b/w instance var and rendring locals in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is difference between

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

and

```
<%= render "form", locals: { user: @user } %>
```

Comment: what do the docs say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html):

```
<%= render partial: "account" %>
```

> This would render “advertiser/_account.html.erb”.

```
<%= render partial: "account", locals: { account: @buyer } %>
```

> This would render “advertiser/_account.html.erb” with `@buyer` passed in as the local variable `account`.

Meaning you can now access the local variable in the rendered file. In your case the `user` variable